# Are Links Allowed?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I have finally finished creating the geography, geology, ecology and prehistory of my alternate Earth on Google Docs.  But is it allowable to post a link on a Stack Exchange post?

Answer (score 8):

The way I understand it so far is that your post should contain all relevant information to the question you want answered. Links should be for references and such, not for important information central to what you are asking about.

Quoting a recent comment by @James, "Links are good but only as reference material. If it is crucial to understanding a post it should be in the question text."

Comment: Well I am pretty sure I absolutely *have* to upvote this answer :)